# Reference AspNetCore Identity in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, reference, asp.net-core, identity

When I try to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity package with NuGet in a Xamarain Android project I get an error, that Microsoft.Win32.Registry 4.0.0 cannot be installed.
Is it possible to reference the Identity package somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't use any arbitrary .NET assembly or Nuget package in a Xamarin project, because Xamarin Android and iOS only support a subset of the full .NET Framework.  In this case there is a dependency on Win32 which is obviously not available on a mobile device.